# iOS 7 uitableviewcell button clicked at long press

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a uitableview cell with 3 buttons inside the content view. when i click on those buttons they work fine but the button's "press down" animation is only showing when tap a bit longer. help need to show it on a single quick tap

Comment: Please always include the relevant parts of your code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour changed in iOS 7
You need to do two changes for this...

**1. For tableview**
set  `tablview.delaysContentTouches = NO;`

**2. In cellForRowAtIndexPath**

First configure your cell and do following

```
for (id obj in cell.subviews)
{
    if ([NSStringFromClass([obj class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellScrollView"])
    {
        UIScrollView *scroll = (UIScrollView *) obj;
        scroll.delaysContentTouches = NO;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey bro really thanks for that .. worked well for me exactly what i wanted

Comment: You r wlcm.. Happy Coding !!

Comment: worked just fine but the scrolling seems to have stopped working .. cant scroll the table. need your help again please

Comment: hey bro iDEV please help me out a bit here. this problem is driving me crazy!!